# pre launch an activity in back stack

Tags: android, performance, launch

To reduce the launch time of application, i want to pre launch the application in  the activity stack if it is not in the stack . I think this will reduce the application launch time.The applications to be pre launched are identified by user context and frequently used applications. Is it possible to pre launch an activity in back stack without bringing it to the front/foreground?

Comment: You can't do this.  Always optimize your activity lifecycle callback methods and never call any blocking methods on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `onCreate()`

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```